# WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL and absolute urls

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a web site that I stored locally into myProject/assets . I want to create a WebView to show it.

I use this code:

```
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Where htmlContent is a string and it is correctly loaded from the local files.

Unfortunately, the site has absolute links: they all start with a "/" and when such a link is clicked by the user, I get this error in the WebView:

```
file:///linkedpage.html not found
```

So, as the documentation says, only relative links and not absolute links are preceded by the BaseURL. Indeed, if I remove the initial "/" from the links, it works.

This can be an error of how the site was written or not, but I'm not the writer of it and I cannot change it (and anyway it makes sense, because the html links are actually in the root of the site, so it's not wrong to call them with a "/".)

How can I manage this? Is there a way to intercept clicks on the links and modify their url, for example? Or can I effectly teach the WebView that "file:///android-asset/" is really the root of the site, and not "file:///", apache-style? Or is there another cleaner solution (besides changing the html file, that I don't want to do)

Comment: "I'm not the writer of it and I cannot change it" -- sure you can. You are in complete control over the assets in the APK. Write a script (e.g., custom Gradle task) that cleans up the HTML from the original that you are getting from wherever. "Or is there another cleaner solution" -- if the only problems are on pure hyperlinks (e.g., `<a>`), attach a `WebViewClient` and do the URL fixup in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: I see, so with a WebViewClient I can intercept the URL and fix it up dynamically with shouldOverrideUrlLoading() ? I will check it out, thanks.